# Name Object Returning SheetName

Tags: vba, object, wildcard, named-ranges

I am trying to loop through all my Named Ranges and set them as a string if they contain a certain substring using a wildcard operator and `LIKE`. Finding the correct Named Range is working as it should.

However, when I set the string to the name of the range, I am getting the full sheet name and not just the Range Name.

`"'SheetName'!Range Name"` should be `"Range Name"`. When using the string later on in the code, it is producing errors because of the sheetname. I could trim and replace, but thought there might be a more direct method to solving the problem.

```
Dim nm as Name
Dim CurrentRange as String   

If nm.Name Like "*Name" Then
    CurrentRange = nm.Name
```

Comment: Seeing all of your code would probably help here

Comment: @urdearboy at first I thought the same, ...except it *is* all the context we need after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Name` is worksheet-scoped. Delete it and make a new one with the same `RefersTo` range, making sure it's at `Workbook` scope:

[image: "New Name" Excel dialog showing Scope field in a red circle]

Sheet-scoped names have the sheet's name in their... name.

[image: debug output of names("the name").Name values: Sheet1!SheetScopeTest1 and BookScopeTest1]

Comment: This was driving me crazy.  (+1)

Comment: Thanks for that answer. However, I have multiple sheets all with the same name so I've had to sheet-scope them to avoid naming errors. It allows me to run the script on multiple sheets without changing too much of my code (apparently). I'm going to mark you response as the answer. I think I'm going to have to take the sheet name and replace it with 'nothing' in the string variable itself.  Thank you!